# Is there a recommended way to run setup in a React component but only after several conditions have been met?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When my component mounts it sends out several requests to an API for data. There is a method in my component that should run *only* when certain requests have been met, and only once.

I’m already using `getDerivedStateFromProps` to run other methods that aren’t so needy, but I’m not sure it’s right since the idea there is to compare new prop values against previous state. I have 4 different props I need check to ensure their previous state was `null` and the new prop has value.

One idea I had was to have an entry in state that looks something like this:

```
this.state = {
    conditions: {
        conditionA: false,
        conditionB: false,
        conditionC: false,
        conditionD: false
    }
}
```

Every time a prop has value, update its related item in state:

```
this.state = {
    conditions: {
        conditionA: false,
        conditionB: false,
        conditionC: true,
        conditionD: false
    }
}
```

Then once all are true, fire up the method. But is there a better way to do this? Is there a recommended way to ensure several props have value before running a method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript has a [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) that you can use to make sure all your Api requests have been completed and then take an action.

The `.then()` callback to `Promise.all` is passed an array that contains the response from all API calls and is triggered when all API calls have succeeded. Even if one fails the `.catch` callback is triggered

```
componentDidMount() {
   const req = urls.map((url) => { // make API requests
     return fetch(url);
   });

   Promise.all(req).then(res => {
      // make the function call here
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these API requests use a technology (like `fetch`) that returns promises (if not, wrap whatever you *are* using in something that returns promises), the fairly standard way to do this would be to do this in `componentDidMount` ([the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) call out network requests as one use case for it):

- Start the requests in parallel
- Use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for them all to complete (or for one of them to fail)
- Call your method that needs the results from a fulfillment handler on the promise from `Promise.all`

For instance:

```
componentDidMount() {
    Promise.all([
        getThingA(),
        getThingB(),
        getThingC(),
        getThingD(),
    ])
    .then(([a, b, c, d]) => {
        this.yourMethod(a, b, c, d);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // Set error state
    });
}
```

(I assume your method eventually calls `setState`.)

Live Example:

```js
const getThing = label => new Promise(
    resolve => setTimeout(resolve, Math.random() * 800, `Value for ${label}`)
);
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        this.state = {
            a: null,
            b: null,
            c: null,
            c: null
        };
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        Promise.all([
            getThing("a"),
            getThing("b"),
            getThing("c"),
            getThing("d"),
        ])
        .then(([a, b, c, d]) => {
            this.yourMethod(a, b, c, d);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // Set error state
        });
    }
    
    yourMethod(a, b, c, d) {
        this.setState({a, b, c, d});
    }
    
    render() {
        const {a, b, c, d} = this.state;
        if (!a || !b || !c || !d) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        }
        return (
            <div>a: {a}, b: {b}, c: {c}, d: {d}</div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use componentDidUpdate:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // check your props values meet your required condition here
  if(!prevProps.condition1 && this.props.condition1 === true && ...) {
    callsomefunction()
  } 
}
```

Comment: When checking on multiple updated prop values — particularly when the requirement is that they were null but no longer are — it’s unlikely that they will all be updated at the same moment, making a statement like this one that will probably never be met.

Comment: I do disagree with that, since you can check that all the conditions are met before calling your function - however I accept that you would need to set some kind of flag to prevent it from running twice or more

Answer (score 0):

You should use `componentDidUpdate` hook:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(Object.values(prevProps).every(val => val)) {
    // do the stuff
  }
}
```

If you want to ignore some state, then you can bypass the state like:

```
const { ignoredState, ...rest } = prevProps
// now, use Object.values to satisfy with rest
```

Or, only use single state for them when all api requests are succeeded by using promise as others stated:

```
// when all promises are done
this.setState({fetched: true})
```

Now, you can just check `fetched` state.